# LACP on stacked HP 2920-48G

Tags: hp, ieee-802.1ax

It is the first time that I am working with HP switches.
I want to use LACP on two stacked HP 2920-48G switches.
Does somebody have an example of the configuration I need to use on both switches ?
Also, I want to connect the two stacked switches with two other stacked switches by using the 10GbE module. Is it just plug and connect or do I have to configure something ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using 1 10Gb port to connect them, you only have to add that link into the VLANs you want to share between the switches, if any. Out of the box, there'd be no configuration on your side w/ 1 link

With 2 links, you will want to form a link aggregation in one of 2 ways. Say you're going to link over 1/49 and 2/49 (first 10Gb on both switches in the stack) to ports 1/50 and 2/50 on the 2nd stack (second 10Gb on both switches in the stack). It's like this:

Stack 1:

```
trunk 1/49,2/49 trk1 lacp
```

Stack 2:

```
trunk 1/50,2/50 trk1 lacp
```

The name 'trk1' becomes the virtual port name. It doesn't have to match on both sides.

The last keyword `lacp` can also be `trunk`. The difference is that `lacp` is a more stateful connection, `trunk` being static port bundle.

Finally, if you have VLANs that need to transit the trunk, you have to allow those across. Just like the other ports are set up, but with the 'trk1' port. If you had, say VLANs 10 and 20, you'd do this on both stacks:

```
vlan 10

tagged trk1

vlan 20

tagged trk1
```

Comment: FYI, you can use the `{}` button in the Stack Exchange GUI editor to auto-monospace any text you have highlighted in the editor.